# i am trying to push an object to an array before adding a new property to that object , but it directly updates the array

Tags: javascript, node.js

how do i get around from this behavior since all i need the updated object for is to just display it to the user and only save the original one

"articles" sent as a response have a category property and in my opinion they shouldn't only the new initialized "data" variable above it should( which is not save to articles array)

```
import articles from "../models/article" // articles empty array
import categories from "../models/category" // categories empty array

export default {
    create(req, res) {
        const value = req.value // object
        const category = req.category // object
        category.forEach(obj => {
            categories.push({ category: obj, articleId: value.id })
        })
        // console.log(categories)
        const bro = articles.push(value)
        console.log(articles)
        if (bro) {
            // const data = value
            value.category = category
            console.log(articles)

            const data = value
            res.status(201).json({
                status: 201,
                message: 'article created successfully',
                articles
            })
        }

    },}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not 100% sure I understand the desired behavior, but if you push an object onto an array, it's just a reference to the original, not a copy. Can you try `articles.push({...value})` or perform some other copy of the objects you don't want aliased using spread syntax, e.g. `category: {...obj}`?

Comment: `if (bro)` will always succeed. `push()` returns the new size of the `articles` array, and it will always be more than 0 after you push something onto the array.

Comment: @BarmarGgorlen got it a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects (including arrays) in javascript are merely pointers. When you push `value` onto `articles` array, you are only pushing a pointer to the original object, so when you modify the original object, that modification applies in both places.

I believe what you want to do is to replace

```
            // const data = value
            value.category = category
            console.log(articles)

            const data = value
```

with

```
            const data = Object.assign({}, value, { category })
```

This will create a completely separate object with all of the previous properties from value, but also adding the category.

Note: ES6 destructuring allows you to simplify it further as just

```
            const data = { ...value, category }
```